# Group by a column and count string in another column in Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe as an output of my python script. I would like to add another column with count per pmid where gene_label is Matched Gene.

The dataframe looks like this:

df

```
       PMID gene_symbol    gene_label gene_mentions
0  33377242       MTHFR  Matched Gene             2
1  33414971       CSF3R  Matched Gene            13
2  33414971         BCR    Other Gene             2
3  33414971        ABL1  Matched Gene             1
4  33414971        ESR1  Matched Gene             1
5  33414971      NDUFB3    Other Gene             1
6  33414971        CSF3    Other Gene             1
7  33414971        TP53  Matched Gene             2
8  33414971         SRC  Matched Gene             1
9  33414971        JAK1  Matched Gene             1
```

The expected output is:

```
       PMID gene_symbol    gene_label gene_mentions   matched_count
0  33377242       MTHFR  Matched Gene             2   1
1  33414971       CSF3R  Matched Gene            13   6
2  33414971         BCR    Other Gene             2   6
3  33414971        ABL1  Matched Gene             1   6
4  33414971        ESR1  Matched Gene             1   6
5  33414971      NDUFB3    Other Gene             1   6
6  33414971        CSF3    Other Gene             1   6
7  33414971        TP53  Matched Gene             2   6
8  33414971         SRC  Matched Gene             1   6
9  33414971        JAK1  Matched Gene             1   6
```

I have used following statement but it is not taking other rows into account.

```
df.loc[df.gene_label == 'Matched Gene', 'PMID'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

First filter to only keep `"Matched Gene"` labels, aggregate and count by `pmid` and `gene_label`, and then join back to original dataframe.

```
# Setup
pmid = [33377242] + [33414971 for i in range(9)]
gene_symbol = ["MTHFR", "CSF3R", "BCR", "ABL1", "ESR1", "NDUFB3", "CSF3", "TP53", "SRC", "JAK1"]
gene_label = ["Matched Gene", "Matched Gene", "Other Gene", "Matched Gene", "Matched Gene", "Other Gene", "Other Gene", "Matched Gene", "Matched Gene", "Matched Gene"]
gene_mentions = [2, 13, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]

df = pd.DataFrame({"pmid":pmid, "gene_symbol":gene_symbol, "gene_label":gene_label, "gene_mentions":gene_mentions})

# Keep matched gene only
filter_df = df[df["gene_label"] == "Matched Gene"]
# Aggregate and count
agg_df = filter_df.groupby(["pmid", "gene_label"], as_index=False).agg(matched_count=("gene_label", "count"))
# Add count back to original dataframe by merging
df = df.merge(agg_df[["pmid", "matched_count"]], on="pmid")
```

output:

```
       pmid gene_symbol    gene_label  gene_mentions  matched_count
0  33377242       MTHFR  Matched Gene              2              1
1  33414971       CSF3R  Matched Gene             13              6
2  33414971         BCR    Other Gene              2              6
3  33414971        ABL1  Matched Gene              1              6
4  33414971        ESR1  Matched Gene              1              6
5  33414971      NDUFB3    Other Gene              1              6
6  33414971        CSF3    Other Gene              1              6
7  33414971        TP53  Matched Gene              2              6
8  33414971         SRC  Matched Gene              1              6
9  33414971        JAK1  Matched Gene              1              6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

# Recreate df from posted question.
text = """PMID gene_symbol    gene_label gene_mentions
0  33377242       MTHFR  Matched Gene             2
1  33414971       CSF3R  Matched Gene            13
2  33414971         BCR    Other Gene             2
3  33414971        ABL1  Matched Gene             1
4  33414971        ESR1  Matched Gene             1
5  33414971      NDUFB3    Other Gene             1
6  33414971        CSF3    Other Gene             1
7  33414971        TP53  Matched Gene             2
8  33414971         SRC  Matched Gene             1
9  33414971        JAK1  Matched Gene             1""".replace(
    " Gene", "_Gene"
)
csv_text = "\n".join(",".join(line.split()) for line in text.splitlines()).replace(
    "_Gene",
    " Gene",
)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_text), delimiter=",")

# Group by gene_label, PMID, get the sizes of "Matched Gene" column
sizes = df.groupby(by=["gene_label", "PMID"]).size()["Matched Gene"]

print(sizes)

# Create a new column that gets the size from sizes df by PMID value.
df["matched_count"] = df.PMID.apply(lambda x: sizes.loc[x])

print(df.to_string())
```

OUTPUT:

```
    PMID
    33377242    1
    33414971    6
    dtype: int64
```

```
       PMID gene_symbol    gene_label  gene_mentions  matched_count
0  33377242       MTHFR  Matched Gene              2              1
1  33414971       CSF3R  Matched Gene             13              6
2  33414971         BCR    Other Gene              2              6
3  33414971        ABL1  Matched Gene              1              6
4  33414971        ESR1  Matched Gene              1              6
5  33414971      NDUFB3    Other Gene              1              6
6  33414971        CSF3    Other Gene              1              6
7  33414971        TP53  Matched Gene              2              6
8  33414971         SRC  Matched Gene              1              6
9  33414971        JAK1  Matched Gene              1              6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby transform to get this done. Since you are looking for specific value of `'Matched Gene'`, you need to filter for that and do the groupby. Then you can ffill the value.

This will do:

```
df['matched_counts'] = df[df['gene_label']=='Matched Gene'].groupby(['PMID'])['gene_label'].transform('count')
df['matched_counts'] = df['matched_counts'].ffill().astype(int)
print (df)
```

The output will be:

```
       PMID gene_symbol    gene_label  gene_mentions  matched_counts
0  33377242       MTHFR  Matched Gene              2               1
1  33414971       CSF3R  Matched Gene             13               6
2  33414971         BCR    Other Gene              2               6
3  33414971        ABL1  Matched Gene              1               6
4  33414971        ESR1  Matched Gene              1               6
5  33414971      NDUFB3    Other Gene              1               6
6  33414971        CSF3    Other Gene              1               6
7  33414971        TP53  Matched Gene              2               6
8  33414971         SRC  Matched Gene              1               6
9  33414971        JAK1  Matched Gene              1               6
```

Alternate, you can also do this:

```
df['matched_counts'] = df.groupby('PMID')['gene_label'].transform(lambda x: sum(x == 'Matched Gene'))
```

The single line will also do the same trick and give you the results as shown above.